# Встроить web-сервер в приложение

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, сервер

Разрабатываю Windows Service. Надо сделать какой-нибудь инструмент управления/мониторинга состояния. Сталкивался с программами, которые при запуске стартуют какой-то свой web-сервер.

Честно искал, как реализовать нечто подобное, но найти не смог.

Моих текущих знаний хватает на то, чтобы сделать сервис и отдельно веб-приложение, которое будет «общаться» с сервисом через сокет-соединение. Но вероятно это не самое лучшее решение?

Кто что подскажет на эту тему?

Comment: _"стартуют какой-то свой web-сервер"_ -- для создание сервиса надо всего несколько строк. пример для owin на c# - [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487125)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Могу предложить два варианта:

1. Воспользоваться OWIN и WebAPI. [Пример](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) селф-хоста на WebAPI.
2. Сделать WCF сервис и хостить его с помощью
   [`ServiceHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost(v=vs.110).aspx). [Пример на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Вкратце по шагам первого варианта:

1) Конфигурируем хост

```
using Owin; 
using System.Web.Http; 

namespace OwinSelfhostSample 
{ 
    public class Startup 
    { 
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder) 
        { 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration(); 
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
                name: "DefaultApi", 
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
            ); 

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

2) Делаем контроллер

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace OwinSelfhostSample 
{ 
    public class ValuesController : ApiController 
    { 
        // GET api/values 
        public IEnumerable<string> Get() 
        { 
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" }; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

3) Стартуем сервис и запрашиваем данные

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace OwinSelfhostSample 
{ 
    public class Program 
    { 
        static void Main() 
        { 
            string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/"; 

            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress)) 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            } 
        } 
    } 
 }
```

---

Вкратце по шагам второго варианта:

1) Объявляем сервис

```
[ServiceContract]
public class HelloWorldService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public string SayHello(string name)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello, {0}", name);
    }
}
```

2) Запускаем

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/hello");

using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), baseAddress))
{
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    host.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    host.Close();
}
```