# Как создать простейший OWIN-сервис в Console Application?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, owin

В новой версии ASP.NET используется OWIN ([Open Web Interface for .NET](http://owin.org/)).
OWIN позволяет создавать приложения, которые не зависят от хоста.
Как создать простейший OWIN-сервис в Console Application?
И как из OWIN-сервиса вывести, например, изображение в браузер?

Comment: тов. минусаторы, ставить минусы без объяснения причины считается дурным тоном.

Comment: Для начала, стоит хотя бы посмотреть что такое OWIN, взглянуть на его реализации, да понять зачем оно вообще надо? :) OWIN - это прямой аналог сервлетов и их контейнеров из Java. Создано оно далеко не для "хочу превратить своё приложение в простенький веб-сервер" - для этого проще/разумнее было бы использовать обычный HttpListener. :)

Comment: @SergeyRufanov как я понял owin - для упрощения переносимости приложения между разными хостами.

Comment: Почитайте про [OWIN](http://dotnet.today/ru/aspnet5-vnext/fundamentals/owin.html), возможно поможет

Answer (score 2):

Простейший OWIN-сервис можно запустить в Console Application.

```
using System;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        WebApp.Start("http://localhost:4321", app => app.Run(ctx => {
            return ctx.Response.WriteAsync("hello");
        }));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

После запуска сервиса, если в браузере открыть http://localhost:4321, то выводится hello.

---

Пример OWIN-сервиса, который возвращает gif с текущей датой+время и создает лог запросов.

```
using System;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
     var s = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
     int index = 0;

     // вывод лога в Console
     Action<IOwinRequest> log = r =>
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} elapsed={1,-10} thread={2,-5} url={3}",
           index++, s.ElapsedMilliseconds, Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId, r.Uri);

     // обработчик запросов
     Func<IOwinContext, Task> handler = ctx => {
        log(ctx.Request);
        var str = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss.fffffff z");  
        ctx.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif; 
        return Task.Run(() => ctx.Response.WriteAsync(ToArray(CreateImage(str)));
     };

     // запуск сервиса
     using (var h = WebApp.Start("http://localhost:4321", app => app.Run(handler)))
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Методы CreateImage и ToArray - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487223/).

В результате в браузере при запросе http://localhost:4321 выводится изображение, а в Console выводится лог запросов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]