# Как в WPF создать изображение и конвертировать его в массив байт?

Tags: c#, wpf, графика

Есть текущая дата+время и ее надо вывести в виде рисунка.
В WinForms это делается достаточно просто.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

static Image CreateImage() {
    var img = new Bitmap(250, 50);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img)) {
        g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
        var str = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss.fffffff z");
        g.DrawString(str, new Font("verdana", 13), System.Drawing.Brushes.Navy, 0, 0);
    }
    return img;
}
static byte[] ToArray(Image img) {
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Gif);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

А как тоже самое сделать в WPF?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

static Visual CreateImage(string str) {
   var visual = new DrawingVisual();
   using (var dc = visual.RenderOpen()) {
      var b = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.Red, Colors.DarkRed, 90);
      var txt = new FormattedText(str,
                       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
                       FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                       new Typeface("verdana"), 13, Brushes.Black);
      txt.MaxTextWidth = 250;
      txt.MaxTextHeight = 25;
      txt.LineHeight = 25;
      txt.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
      dc.DrawRectangle(b, null, new Rect(0, 0, txt.MaxTextWidth, txt.MaxTextHeight));
      txt.SetForegroundBrush(Brushes.White, 0, str.Length);
      dc.DrawText(txt, new Point(0, 0));
   }
   return visual;
}

static byte[] ToArray(Visual visual) {
   var b = VisualTreeHelper.GetContentBounds(visual);
   var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)b.Width, (int)b.Height, 
                                    96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
   rtb.Render(visual);
   var frame = BitmapFrame.Create(rtb);
   var encoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();
   encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
   var ms = new MemoryStream();
   encoder.Save(ms);
   ms.Position = 0;
   return ms.ToArray();
}
```